# How to sort list items by substring value ? c#

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist, foreach, listitem

I have a list which contains infos about some orders

Order Info:

```
STORAGEA ----- 2,311 € ----- 8 PCS ----- 08:55:02.933
COMPANYX ----- 6,435 € ----- 80 PCS ----- 08:59:07.751
FACTORYT ----- 22,20 € ----- 80 PCS ----- 08:45:04.686
```

As you can see my list items arent sorted properly, as order times are mixed

Desired output would be:

```
FACTORYT ----- 22,20 € ----- 80 PCS ----- 08:45:04.686
STORAGEA ----- 2,311 € ----- 8 PCS ----- 08:55:02.933
COMPANYX ----- 6,435 € ----- 80 PCS ----- 08:59:07.751
```

My current code:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

   

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> mylist = new List<string>(new string[] { "STORAGEA ----- 2,311 € ----- 8 PCS ----- 08:55:02.933",
 "COMPANYX ----- 6,435 € ----- 80 PCS ----- 08:59:07.751", 
"FACTORYT ----- 22,20 € ----- 80 PCS ----- 08:45:04.686" });

            listBox1.DataSource = mylist;
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help from you guys :)

Comment: The first thing you should do is to parse the strings into a proper class with separate properties for each of the substrings (and use the appropriate types, e.g. `DateTime` for the times and `decimal` for the costs). Then you will easily be able to use Linq's `OrderBy()` and (if necessary) `ThenBy()` to obtain your desired ordering.

Comment: Matthew Watson is right. Even if you can use something like this: `mylist = mylist
  .OrderBy(x=> Convert.ToDateTime(x.Substring(x.Length-12, 12)))
  .ToList();` - it isn't proper way to sort kind of data. Create custom class accordingly to Matthew's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, read comments to the question.

Imagine, you have to work on specific objects, using proper data types.

Here's sample class:

```
class Order
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int CountOfPieces { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderTime { get; set; }
}
```

You can "convert" `List<string>` into ordered `List<Order>` this way:

```
List<Order> myProperData = mylist
    .Select(x=>x.Split(new string[]{" ", "-", "€"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .Select(x=> new Order()
    {
        CompanyName = x[0],
        Price = Convert.ToDouble(x[1]),
        CountOfPieces = Convert.ToInt32(x[2]),
        OrderTime = Convert.ToDateTime(x[4])
    })
    .OrderBy(x=>x.OrderTime) //sort orders by OrderTime!
    .ToList();
```

As you can see `myProperData` is the list of orders. You can manage your data (add/remove/sort) the way you want.

For further details, please see: [Classes - C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes)